# How can I exit a specific kernel?

Tags: kernel

According to the documentation, the following are true:

1. The `Exit[]` command "terminates a Wolfram Language kernel session."
2. The `LocalSubmit[expr]` command "submits a task to evaluate expr in a separate kernel."

Then, in theory, I should be able to do the following:

```
LocalSubmit[
    (Pause[10]; "Hello, World!"),
    HandlerFunctions -> <|"TaskFinished" -> MessageDialog|>
]
```

and then, within 10 seconds, call

```
Exit[]
```

without interrupting the first computation. But all my experiments show that calling `Exit[]` results in the aborting of the first computation (even though it is expected to be running on a different kernel).

Is there a way to call the `Exit[]` command without affecting the `LocalSubmit` call? In short, is there a way to start a fire-and-forget call, and then continue working normally in a notebook without affecting the asynchronous call?

Comment: I think the separate kernel is still managed by the main kernel. It’s probably a subkernel instead of a stand-alone.

Comment: I guess so. I only wish the documentation had made it clearer. So, I suppose there is no way to issue an `Exit[]` command without interrupting a fire-and-forget call?